Baseboard heating removal
I need to cut into the copper and cap the end,is there another water shut off I need to use besides main? Do not want to flood the house!

The main will turn off all the water to the house.  There should be other closer shutoff valves for hot water only, maybe for that heater.

If you are removing the baseboard heating, you'll want to shut off the water being supplied to the heating loop (varies depending on our boiler setup) and shut off the boiler, and drain the heating loop before you cut things open, or you will have at least a limited flood from the water in the boiler loop.
If you have shut off the supply to the boiler, you should not need to shut off the main. If you shut off either the main or the supply to the boiler and don't drain the boiler loop, considerable water will come out when you cut the baseboard heating loop, depending on how much of the system is above the point that you cut. You may also damage the boiler if it fires with the heating loop empty.
If you have separate water heating for domestic hot water, removing baseboard heating and its boiler is relatively simple. If you have a hot water coil (US terminology) or a combi boiler (rest of the planet, evidently) that heats both the heating loop AND the domestic hot water, and you want it to continue to heat the domestic hot water, it's a bit more complicated to remove just the heating loops.

Also there's often an expansion tank with the hot water baseboard loop that will provide additional water into the heating loop as the system is drained, so it's especially important to properly drain the system first before opening anything up to prevent any flooding.
